# What does double slash // in `cd //` mean in Linux?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, directory-structure, cd

I've entered a command `cd //` instead of `cd /` by mistake and instead of getting an error as I'd expect the shell (Bash) showed a prompt as if I'm in the `//` directory:-

```
<username>@<hostname>://$
<username>@<hostname>://$ pwd
//
```

Listing the content of the directory shows that it is the same as `/`.

So what exactly `cd //` do and what's the difference from `cd /`?

Comment: There's no difference. Try "//////////", it'll work as well.

Comment: "//////////" works, but I get a different prompt with a single '/'.

Comment: Belongs on Linux stack, it's clearly off-topic here.

Comment: The bash builtin `pwd` command remembers the string you gave it (but normalizes it in some cases). `/bin/pwd` infers the full path from the location of your current directory, traversing `..` links as needed, and will print just `/`.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Actually it means nothing and is ignored.

From the [Bash FAQ E10:](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/FAQ):

> E10) Why does 'cd //' leave $PWD as '//'?
>
> POSIX.2, in its description of 'cd', says that three or more leading
>   slashes may be replaced with a single slash when canonicalizing the
>   current working directory.
>
> This is, I presume, for historical compatibility. Certain versions of
>   Unix, and early network file systems, used paths of the form
>   //hostname/path to access 'path' on server 'hostname'.

Also the [Unix standards](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/basedefs/xbd_chap04.html#tag_04_11) states:

> A pathname that begins with two successive slashes may be interpreted
>   in an implementation-defined manner, although more than two leading
>   slashes shall be treated as a single slash.

Comment: **The `//` does not mean nothing**. It's defined by POSIX such that it may be _interpreted in an implementation-defined manner_, which means the system is free to do with it what it will. For example, on Cygwin, `cd //` followed by `ls` eventually returns `ls: reading directory '.': Permission denied`. whereas `cd /` followed by `ls` returns a listing of the root directory. (Cygwin uses a root of `//`  to identify //hostname/path.)

Answer (score 21):

This [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/23809) on AskUbuntu confirms that they are the same directory. Further, it helpfully quotes from the [POSIX Pathname Resolution specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap04.html#tag_04_11):

> A pathname consisting of a single slash shall resolve to the root directory of the process. A null pathname shall not be successfully resolved. A pathname that begins with two successive slashes may be interpreted in an implementation-defined manner, although more than two leading slashes shall be treated as a single slash.